# For some reason my python code is skipping a certain part of code (pygame)

Tags: python

Loging in with jack works fine but I cant login with jake even thought he exists in the array. It just skips the whole for loop "for i in storedusername". An help would be grateful.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


storedusername = ["jack","jack","jack","jake","jack","jack","jack",] # The place where the username is stored
storedpass = ["abcde","abcde","abcde","12345","abcde","abcde","abcde",] # The current place where the password is stored


Login = False

def login(): # Function used to login
global Login # Global the logins fucntion
Login = False # Sets Login to false
user = input("Enter Username: ") # User enters the username that they would like to login with
print(user)
for i in storedusername: # Loops through the items in the list
    if i == user: # Compares the items in the list with the username that the user has entered
        print("user found") # If the user was found then the program will tell the user that 
        pos = int(storedusername.index(user)) # Finds the position where the username is stored
        print(pos)
    for j in range(0,10): # Has 10 tries to do this loop
        password = input("Enter Password: ") # The user enters the password which they think matches with the username.
        #for i in range(0,10):
        if password == storedpass[pos]: # Goes to the position where the password matches the username is stored and compares the values.
            print("password match username") # Program returns if the username and password match
            Login = True # Turns login to True
            return Login # Returnes Login
            break

        else:
            print("Pasword does not match try again") # If the password does not match then the program will notify it.
                

    print("too many attempts close the program") # If there are too many attempts than it will close.
else:
    print("not found") # If the username is not found than it will be promted that it is not found.
return Login # Returns login.

login()
```

Comment: Hi. It would be easier if you would strip off the code unneded here to investigate your issue. Please leave only `login` function, (with needed `storedusername`, etc.). How does it behave? I checked that and it seems that it comes into that loop and finds the user.

Comment: Ok it has been done

Comment: For me it doesent print out "user found" nor the pos

Comment: Now it's stripped too much and you don't have passwords.

Comment: yep sorry should be fixed

Comment: I added as an answer the whole block which works for me. It's not possible to print the code in any nice way in the comments.

Comment: It is working for me, test with "jack" and "abcde" ... the problem is the print("Pasword does not match try again") which is not written in the right place/indetation. And as you have several user with same name, you cannot really test, this may cause problems. Please spcecify the value you input to show quickly what goes wrond, and what is your precise question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right to think that the indentation wasn't correct. As you had it before, if you entered a username not present in the list, you would still be asked for the password ten times for each user in `storedusername` (a total of 70 times!). Moving the block from `for i in range(0,10)` one indentation further fixes it.

```
    for i in storedusername: ############ It skips this loop
        if i == user:
            print("user found")
            pos = int(storedusername.index(user))
            print(pos) ########### All the way up to here

            # >>>> indent here
            for i in range(0,10): # Has 10 tries to do this loop
                password = input("Enter Password: ") # The user enters the password which they think matches with the username.
                #for i in range(0,10):
                if password == storedpass[pos]: # Goes to the position where the password matches the username is stored and compares the values.
                    print("password match username") # Program returns if the username and password match
                    Login = True # Turns login to True
                    return Login # Returnes Login
                    break
                else:
                    print("Pasword does not match try again") # If the password does not match then the program will notify it.
            # >>>>>

            print("too many attempts close the program") # If there are too many attempts than it will close.
        else:
            print("not found") # If the username is not found than it will be promted that it is not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `i` both for outer and inner loop, so it is changed inside.

It must be:

```
for i in ... :
    ...
    for j in ... :
        ...
```

Comment: It's good point. I mean this does not break the things there but it would be better to change that `i` and `j` in some more meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

You may see that not working because of wrong indentation of that

```py
    else:
        print(
            "Pasword does not match try again")  # If the password does not match then the program will notify it.

print(
    "too many attempts close the program")  # If there are too many attempts than it will close.
```

block.

Please move it to to left, and it should be better.

---

That modified version

```py
storedusername = ["jack", "jack", "jack", "jake", "jack", "jack",
                  "jack", ]  # The place where the username is stored
storedpass = ["abcde", "abcde", "abcde", "12345", "abcde", "abcde",
              "abcde", ]  # The current place where the password is stored
(width, height) = (644, 412)

Login = False


def login():  # Function used to login
    global Login  # Global the logins fucntion
    Login = False  # Sets Login to false
    user = input(
        "Enter Username: ")  # User enters the username that they would like to login with
    print(user)
    for i in storedusername:  ############ It skips this loop
        if i == user:
            print("user found")
            pos = int(storedusername.index(user))
            print(pos)  ########### All the way up to here
        for i in range(0, 10):  # Has 10 tries to do this loop
            password = input(
                "Enter Password: ")  # The user enters the password which they think matches with the username.
            # for i in range(0,10):
            if password == storedpass[
                pos]:  # Goes to the position where the password matches the username is stored and compares the values.
                print(
                    "password match username")  # Program returns if the username and password match
                Login = True  # Turns login to True
                return Login  # Returnes Login
                break

            # --> wrong indentation
            else:
                print(
                    "Pasword does not match try again")  # If the password does not match then the program will notify it.

        print(
            "too many attempts close the program")  # If there are too many attempts than it will close.
        # <-- wrong indentation
    else:
        print(
            "not found")  # If the username is not found than it will be promted that it is not found.
    return Login  # Returns login.


# register()
login()
```

allows for

```
Enter Username: jack
jack
user found
0
Enter Password: abde
Pasword does not match try again
Enter Password: abcde
password match username

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

I'm not going to modify the flow of your solution, but I'd suggest to write comments before the line, not in it. Also you should avoid variables shadowing (using the same variable like `i` in different scopes). The last thing is that you got slightly wrong indent for password checking - it was run even wihtout matched name. I allowed myself to propose version with all these modifiactions. Please take a look on that:

```py
def login():
    """ Function used to login"""

    # Global the logins fucntion
    global Login
    Login = False

    # User enters the username that they would like to login with
    user = input("Enter Username: ")
    print(user)

    for stored_user_name in stored_user_names:
        if stored_user_name == user:
            print("user found")
            pos = int(stored_user_names.index(user))

            # Has 10 tries to do this loop
            for try_attempt in range(0, 10):
                # The user enters the password which they think matches with the username.
                password = input("Enter Password: ")

                # Goes to the position where the password matches the username is stored and compares the values.
                if password == storedpasswords[pos]:
                    # Program returns if the username and password match
                    print("password match username")
                    Login = True  # Turns login to True
                    return Login  # Returnss Login

                else:
                    # If the password does not match then the program will notify it.
                    print("Password does not match try again")

            # If there are too many attempts than it will close.
            print("too many attempts close the program")

    else:
        # If the username is not found than it will be promted that it is not found.
        print("not found")
    return Login
```

Comment: Sorry move what specifically to the left?

Comment: That `else` block. It's already done in my code, and it should work. Please try.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I have some more comments, but put that into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the commenting advice will do.

Comment: Good. And please mark that as solved. It will help whenever someone will seek for such things in future.